# Getting content using wikipedia API

Tags: php, api, parsing, wikipedia-api

How can I get the entire first section/paragraph of a Wikipedia article including the first image with a single request?

What I've tried so far (the following url) returns only a snippet:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=search&srsearch=camera&srlimit=1

Comment: Probably it's written in the docs: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: I can't find it, that's why i finally decided to ask.

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting the wikitext, use [`prop=revisions` with `rvsection=0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stack+Overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0). If you're wanting HTML, you can add [`rvparse=1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stack+Overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&rvparse=1) to that query or you can use [`action=parse`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Stack+Overflow&section=0).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the entire first section/paragraph of a Wikipedia article including the first image with a single request?

It's not possible to do that in one request.

Comment: ok, can you please suggest a way to do it even without a single request? sample code maybe?